# iphone-How to check for collisions between elements in NSMutable array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

Background:I am using XCode 3.1. Please do not comment about this.

Problem: I have two buttons, fire and make meteor, which make UIImageViews when clicked. I add these UIImageviews to two seperate NSMutable arrays, bullets and meteors. How would I check for collisions between any element in the bullet array and an element in the meteor array. Also, if there were a collision, how would I then remove the bullet and the meteor in question from the view. Thank you. Here is my code so far:

```
-(IBAction)createBullets:(id)sender{
        UIImageView *two = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lazerBeam.png"]];
    CGRect rectTwo = CGRectMake((image.center.x), (image.center.y - 45), 7, 20);
    [two setFrame:rectTwo];
    [self.view addSubview:two];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveBulletOne:) userInfo:two repeats:YES];
    [bulletImageViews addObject:two]; 
}

-(IBAction)createMeteors:(id)sender{

    UIImageView *one = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Meteor.png"]];
    CGRect rectOne = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (310), arc4random() % (1), 35, 35);
    [one setFrame:rectOne];
    [self.view addSubview:one];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(moveMeteorOne:) userInfo:one repeats:YES];
    [meteorImageViews addObject:one];



}
```

I also move the meteors and bullets using a NSTimer to a move function, but that is irrelevant. Basically, I want to check when a bullet collides with a meteor, and when that happens, to remove the meteor and bullet in question from the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic O(n^2) search, check every bullet against every meteor. This is probably  fine for a small app, but it can be optimized using spatial partitioning methods to reduce the amount of checks required (quadtrees etc).  You want to create a "toRemove" array rather than removing in place so that the array is not modified while enumerating.

```
NSMutableArray* bulletsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* meteorsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (UIImageView* bullet in bulletImageViews)
    {
        for (UIImageView* meteor in meteorImageViews)
        {
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bullet.frame, meteor.frame)
            {
                 [bulletsToRemove addObject:bullet];
                 [meteorsToRemove addObject:meteor];
                 break;
            }
         }
    }

[bulletsToRemove makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[meteorsToRemove makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

[bulletImageViews removeObjectsInArray:bulletsToRemove];
[meteorImageViews removeObjectsInArray:meteorsToRemove];
```

Comment: What would the code for the removeObjectsFromArray method be?

Comment: @user2607954 my mistake, the correct method is removeObjectsInArray

Comment: Where would I put this code? Write now I have it in my NSTimer called move bullet function, and the collision still is not registered.

Comment: @user2607954 idk about your code.. probably in the main timer loop..

Comment: Correction, the collision is detected. However, the uiimageviews for the bullet and the meteor are not removed from the view.

Comment: @user2607954 ah ill edit the code and add that part

Comment: @user2607954 should be good to go now

Comment: Oh, I fixed it. I removed it from the view by implementing the [bullet removeFromSuperview];

Comment: @user2607954 yes I guess you can either do it like my code. Or right when its added to the bulletsToRemove array.

Comment: @user2607954 if my answer solved the problem you should accept it. (in case you didn't know)